# Como simplificar a chamada de tradução no i18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Veja este exemplo abaixo de uma tradução faltando:

```
{
  "errors": [
    "Email translation missing: pt-BR.activerecord.errors.models.artemis/user.attributes.email.taken"
  ]
}
```

Para resolver essa tradução devo seguir exatamente a estrutura gerada acima:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      artemis/user:
        attributes:
          cpf:
            taken: 'Aqui vem a tradução'
```

Minha duvida está se existe uma forma mais automatizada e simples para simplificar essa tradução? Veja abaixo:

```
errors:
  messages:
    cpf: 'Aqui vem a tradução'
```

Sei que posso colocar a frente da validação algo como `message: I18n.t('errors.messages.cpf')`, mas ter que fazer essa inserção em toda validação iria deixar o código bem poluído.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o `ActiveRecord` é quem valida ele já tem sua hierarquia de chamada no arquivo do `I18n`, ou seja deve-se seguir sua convenção, como você já demonstrou em sua pergunta. Para mudar esse comportamento você teria que sobrescrever isso no `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 2):

Exatamente como o Luiz comentou, esta regra de nomenclatura é convenção do Rails.

Existe uma forma, que seria criar um validate no model chamando uma função, e adicionar um erro "customizado" pro erro acontecido.
Ex:

```
validates_presence_of :email, :message => "mensagem de erro com outra tradução"
```

Ou também, daria para criar um validade no model, da seguinte forma:

```
class MeuModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   validate :email

   def parent_released
     errors.add(:email, "mensagem de erro com outra tradução") if 
     deu_erro?
   end
end
```

Como solução para facilitar o gerenciamento de traduções, existe uma ferramenta chamada "Localeapp", https://www.localeapp.com...
Com esta GEM https://github.com/Locale/localeapp voce consegue baixar as traduções criadas facilmente para o seu projeto.

Espero que ajude! Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar este arquivo: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/pt-BR.yml na pasta `config/locales/`

Depois adicionar esta linha no arquivo `config/application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
```